# How to get menu shortcuts working in C# GUI-DLL?

Tags: c#, python, user-interface, dll, windows-10

I build a C# GUI running on windows10, which is controlled via Python and Python module CLR.

Unfortunately the menue shortcuts are not working. If I build the GUI as .EXE, the shortcuts work, the call the handler in GUI-C#-code, and I can forward it to Python code. But if I build the project as DLL, I can't call the menue items be [CTRL]+[S] for example.

The GUI is started via Python:

```
clr.AddReference(os.getcwd() + os.sep + "PadTestGuiC.dll")
import PadTestGuiC  #this imports previous loaded class from dll
pgui = PadTestGuiC.PadTestGuiC()
pgui.m_pythonCB = pgui.pythonCallbackHandler(cbs1s1)
pguit = Thread(target=pgui.ShowDialog)
```

and this is the handler in c# gui:

```
    private void helpToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        addDoIts("help."); #this also shows information in textbox
    }
```

It's not called if GUI is build as DLL. 
I found no information about this issue. Why doen't this work? Do I need to create a workaround, by capturing all keystrokes? What's the simplest way, to make shortcuts working again?

Comment: Controlled how? By using window messages? Accessibility? Are you sure you're sending the messages to the correct window? You're asking for help with code you haven't posted or described.

Comment: I added code for you, although it's no code issue I think. The C# handler, which is automatically generated is not called if it's a DLL. 
If you really interested: generate a GUI. create simple menu enties. add shortcuts with the GUI editor (you don't need to generate any code until here) now modify a textbox from the menu entry.
build it as DLL. you can call the menu entries by mouse or keyboard [alt]+[...] bot for me, the shortcuts don't work.
I don't aks for help with code. I ask for help with what's the difference between C# exe and dll gui menue behavior.

Comment: There's no such thing as a DLL GUI, C# or otherwise. Both on Windows and Linux the menus are resources managed by the windowing system. Clicks, shortucts etc are all messages sent by the OS to an application' message processing pump which takes action. *Libraries* don't execute so they have no message pump. Only *executables* run. If you call that DLL from a Python process, that's the one that runs the pump. Keyboard or mouse messages should be sent to that process (specifically, its main window)

Comment: If I use the mouse or keyboard with the menue, it reacts on clicks automatically and executes the code, which I added in the function, which was created automatically by VisualStudio. Without creating a additional handler. Please try it yourself, before saying, it's not this way.

Comment: That's not how Windows works. That `automatically` part is the OS itself sending key or mouse events to the application's message pump. On the other hand, if you load the library itself, *why do you try to click anything at all?* Just call the methods themselves. Business logic shouldn't be placed in event handlers anyway, so you can just call the objects and methods that implement the functionality you want.

Comment: The other feature used to control applications is Accessibility. Windows gives access to all GUI elements through Accessibility interfaces so products like screen readers or speech recognizers can find out what's on the screen and use it. That's also used to automate applications that weren't written with automation in mind and don't expose a nice API that could be called.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for trying to help me. I didn't wanted to write tons of handlers for every GUI button or menu entry. So I send all actions via one message-callback in a extra thread to python, there the messages are added to a list, where a extra message parser loop executes, what's to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, by creating a workaround:

I added 2 additional global handlers for keyboard events on the form.

```
    private void PadTestGuiC_Key(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_keylock >0)
            return;
        string s = e.KeyData.ToString();
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Length >2)     //it's modifier only
            return;
        m_keylock = 1;
        addDoIts("mnu:" + s);
    }

    private void PadTestGuiC_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        m_keylock = 0;
    }
```

This messages are added to the toolStripMenu detectors. For example:

```
if cmd in ("getStatusToolStripMenuItem", "mnu:S, Shift, Control"):
   doThis...

if cmd in ("getTimeToolStripMenuItem","mnu:T, Control"):
   doThat...
```

this executes, if mouse or keyboard use the menue strip and also works, if a shortcut is used.

Unfortunately I've to add a `,"mnu:?, ????"` to every entry. That, and the manually shortcut detection was, what I wanted to avoid.